# Best practices for using Hg with Grails?

Tags: version-control, grails, mercurial

What should I check in/not check in?  Since many of the files are sometimes auto-generated I'm not entirely sure how to handle this using version control...does it have something to do with tags?

For instance in ANT, I **know** not to check-in my target/bin directories...but Grails adds another level of confusion to this...since some of code is generated and some of it is not.

(It may become clearer as I go...but it seems to be that there needs to be some way of being able to tell what was just generated and what was modified by a developer so that it needs to be placed in version control)

Comment: Eh, anymore answers on this one?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the .hgignore directory I've got on my most recent grails project (with a couple of project specific things taken out):

```
syntax: glob

out
target
logs
*.iml
.idea
*.iws
*.war
workspace.xml
lib/build
lib/compile
lib/runtime
lib/test
~$*
stacktrace.log
*.tmproj
*.launch
reports/
*.orig
*.zip

.DS_Store
*/.DS_Store
web-app/WEB-INF/classes
cobertura.ser
```

Comment: @Ted I take it your using Intellj?

Comment: Yep, intellij if I want to debug and textmate for quick stuff.

If you don't use those, you could remove the .idea, *.iws, *.iml and *.tmproj files

Answer (score 2):

The generated code in Grails should be placed under version control. It's not secondary executable code that is generated by the build process like class files, but instead is code that is part of your source. The generated code is intended to be just a starting point for your application and will most likely be modified at some point anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Also check this:

http://www.grails.org/Checking+Projects+into+SVN

and this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201578/what-grails-project-files-should-not-be-added-to-version-control-grails-1-3-x)