# What grails project files should not be added to version control? (Grails 1.3.x)

Tags: version-control, grails, ignore, gitignore, hgignore

(This question has been asked before, but a while back: [Suggestions for Grails .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470833/suggestions-for-grails-gitignore); it was answered for grails 1.0.x)

What files in a Grails 1.3.x project should not be included in version control?

Answer (score 3):

See http://grails.org/Checking+Projects+into+SVN - it has a short list of ignores.

I would include .settings/ but I tend to keep .classpath and .project in source control because they change with the project. Then again, perhaps it's better simply to run `grails integrate-with --eclipse`.

Comment: My project plugins come under %user_home%\.grails\1.3.7\projects , should these be checked in ?, I have made some changes in some of the plugins, how do i ensure that they are not lost ?

Comment: @Peter Ledbrook it would be great to have an update of this for Grails 3.0.1 as the link is quite out of date.

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore:

```
# Maven output directory
target/

# Eclipse Project files
.classpath
.project
.settings/

# OS X generated files
.DS_Store
```